# How to recreate a DocumentFile folder from a previous URI

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

If we create a DocumentFile using the tree URI returned from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

```
DocumentFile dir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, treeUri);
```

And then create a sub directory

```
DocumentFile subDir = pickedDir.createDirectory("example");
Uri uri = subDir.getUri();
```

How can we later recreate the sub directory using the above URI?

Comment: A directory can be created only once. Its unclear why you wanna recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, you have to use DocumentsContract.createDocument() with the URI of the previously created directory.

Comment: Nice, i might need this, im not the only who has to answer his own questions